# Have many p:tree s with just one selection variable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have many `<p:tree>` items all of them have the selection enabled, but  I want all of them using the same selection variable, but just the last tree created set the values, the others selections are not passed to the managed bean.

This is the code of who creates the trees

```
<p:accordionPanel>
    <c:forEach  items="#{grupController.listRepo}" var="repo">
        <p:tab title="#{repo.nome}">
            <p:tree cache="false" dynamic="true"
                    value="#{grupController.listRepo(repo.id)}" var="item"
                    selectionMode="checkbox" id="arbol"
                    selection="#{grupController.categoriesAutorized()}">
                <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open"
                            collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
                </p:treeNode>
            </p:tree>
        </p:tab>
    </c:forEach>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

in my managed bean I have this variable

```
private   TreeNode[] categoriesAutorized;
```

Like I said before this variable is empty always but when the selected items are from the last tree.

How can I fix this behavior and have a full list of selected items in one single variable?

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.1

Thanks in advance for your time and answers

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using the datamodel-backed variant of the accordion panel?

Comment: @kolossus I'm sorry but I don´t understand your question

Comment: Are you aware of an alternative to the `c:forEach` method of creating iterative child components inside an accordion panel?

Comment: @kolossus No, but if you recommend something to read I'll really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

[`<p:accordionPanel/>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml) has a `value` attribute, that allows you to build the content of your accordion based on the items in a backing list. Using this, your example would now look like

```
        <p:accordionPanel value="#{grupController.listRepo}" var="repo">
            <p:tab title="#{repo.nome}">
                 <p:tree cache="false" dynamic="true"
                         value="#{grupController.listRepo(repo.id)}" var="item"
                         selectionMode="checkbox" id="arbol"
                         selection="#{grupController.categoriesAutorized()}">
                       <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open"
                                   collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                             <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
                       </p:treeNode>
                 </p:tree>
             </p:tab>             
        </p:accordionPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ajax based selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/events.xhtml). The setter for grupController.categoriesAutorized should be there but with an empty body then.

In the nodeSelect and nodeUnselect listeners, you have to pop or pull the selected nodes from the list yourself